# Uable to generate adapter application - ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am quite new to ember.js. I have been working on the [tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/installing-addons/) and having issue with generating adapter application.

When i run the command  **ember generate adapter application** i can see message saying installing adapter and installing adapter-test  but no file is getting generated in the folder structure .[image]

**Package.json**

```html
{
  "name": "super-rentals",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Small description for super-rentals goes here",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
    "lint:js": "eslint .",
    "start": "ember serve",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ember/jquery": "^0.6.0",
    "@ember/optional-features": "^0.7.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~3.11.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.7.3",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^5.1.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-mirage": "^0.4.15",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-tutorial-style": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-data": "~3.11.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-qunit": "^4.4.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.0.1",
    "ember-source": "~3.11.1",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.0.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.* || >= 10.*"
  }
}
```

Comment: What ember-cli version?

Comment: ember cli version is  "ember-cli": "~3.11.0"

Comment: Other generators work?

Comment: No , i have tried model and it has the same issue too

Comment: You might want to ask on the [Ember Discord Community](https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS) Help channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola @Divakar, thanks for your question! And Welcome to Ember

Looking at your question it seems like it could be related to an issue that we had recently in ember-data where the generators were broken. I think they were fixed in `ember-data@3.11.1` but from your package.json it would seem that you have `ember-data@3.11.0`

If you want to update ember-data and see if the issue is still there you can run the following:

```
npm i ember-data@latest
```

Also @Lux was asking if other generators work, the examples that you gave were all related to ember-data  so there is a possibility that they were all affected by the same bug. If updating ember-data doesn't fix your issue can you try generating a route or a controller and see if they work

Edit: I have just run into this same issue with an up-to-date Ember app and I can confirm that it is not fixed yet.

For now you can get this working by creating the files yourself. For an the application adapter you can create the file `app/adapters/application.js` and paste this in the file:

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
});
```

If you want to build a model you can create a file in models with the name you want. For example you can create `app/models/rental.js` and put this in it:

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
});
```

If you create those files manually they will be almost exactly what you would have seen if you created them with the generator

Comment: Thanks , @real_ate updating my pom "ember-data": "~3.11.1", dint work . but i tried creating files manually and it worked like charm.

Comment: The bug was fixed in Ember Data `v3.11.3`, which was released a few hours ago.

Comment: @jelhan I think they tried to fix it in 3.11.3 but it doesn't seem to be working. I just created a brand new ember app and ran `ember g model` and the files weren't created 